# Trying to create a test class for an Apex class with invocablemehtod

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have the following Apex class

```
public class sendAnEmailChk {
  @InvocableMethod(label='Test' description='sends an email')
  public static void sendEmailWithAttachment(List<id> listofQuoteHeader) {
    Map<Id, Chcks__c> quotesMap = new Map<Id, Chcks__c>(
      [SELECT id FROM Chcks__c WHERE Id IN :listofQuoteHeader]
    );
    for (Id QuoteHeaderid : listofQuoteHeader) {
      PageReference pref = page.Chck;
      pref.getParameters().put('id', (Id) QuoteHeaderid);
      pref.setRedirect(true);
      Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
      Blob b = pref.getContentAsPDF();
      attachment.Body = b;
      attachment.Name =
        Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') +
        ' ' +
        'Quote' +
        '.pdf';
      attachment.IsPrivate = false;
      attachment.ParentId = QuoteHeaderid;
      attachment.Name = 'Sign.pdf';
      insert attachment;
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
      attach.setFileName('AttachmentEmailFile.pdf');
      attach.setBody(b);
      semail.setSubject('Quote Issued');
      String[] emailIds = new List<String>{ '123@gmail.com' };
      semail.setToAddresses(emailIds);
      semail.setPlainTextBody('Please find the attached quote details');
      semail.setFileAttachments(
        new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>{ attach }
      );
      Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>{ semail });
    }
  }
}
```

I am struggling to create a decent test class with enough code coverage.
Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have done and where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. We are not here to write your code for you, but if you [edit] your question to include your best attempt at the unit test code, as well as information on which lines you can't cover, then we'd be able to help you more specifically.